# gparted label file system greyed out

Tags: gparted, disk-usage, rename

I bought a new SSD hard drive recently to use as a backup, and when I mount it to my machine it shows up mounted at `/media/[USER]/Extreme SSD/`  <-- yes, that's a space there.

I *hate* having spaces in the names of files or directories, so I open up gparted to change this, but when I right-click on the drive and look at the menu item "Label File System", it's greyed out. No idea why. I've unmounted the drive, and I've changed the "Name" of partition, but that doesn't help. I want to be able to navigate to any path in the drive without having to worry about spaces.

Any idea why I can't change the label? Do I need to change something else? It's exFat format and I'm on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Default mount is by label. You may need exFAT driver? But you should not use any Microsoft formats for Linux backup. Microsoft does not support ownership & permissions, so you do not have  a good backup. You can backup data only, but then have to manually restore settings. Since data should have same setting, it can be restored. But rest of system have many different settings. There may be a couple of files in /home's hidden settings that also need to be different than most data in /home.

Comment: Thanks, I don't care what file format is used, so I can reformat and create a new backup if necessart, But is the issue that I cannot change label if the file format is exFAT? If I change to ext4 can I then change the label however I want?

Comment: If you use gparted to create new partition, it has options to create labels. There now are two labels, one file system & one partition for gpt partitioned drives which you should use. You may have to change to gpt first from default MBR(msdos).  I also have changed with Disks and terminal.

Comment: Have you tried unmounting the SSD before changing the label? Step 1: Unmount the drive. Step 2: Change the label. Step 3: Apply.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to reformat the partition to ntfs and select a label for it (without spaces). I did not find a way how to do it without a loss of data though.